# Загрузка файлов на сервер

Tags: php, upload, codeigniter, mysql

Здравствуйте. Я не русский, поэтому извините, если у меня будут грамматические ошибки... Вопрос такой: использую фреймворк Codeigniter, хочу сделать загрузку файлов на сервер. Я сделал это, но когда хочу сохранить данные в базе (+src код загруженного файла), возникают ошибки. Вот кусок кода:

*VIEW.php*

```
   echo form_open_multipart("admin/addnews","add_form");
   $title = array(
        'name' => 'title',
        'value'=> '',
         );
    .......
    echo form_input($title);
    <inрut type="file" name="userfile" size=20>
    echo form_submit(array('name'=>'add'),"add news");
```

---

*model.php*

```
    function addNews(){

        $title = $this->input->post("title");
        $date = $this->input->post("date");
                ....................

                $uploaddir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/";
        $temp = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

        $uploadfile = $uploaddir.$temp;
        echo $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($userfile, $uploadfile);
    }
```

Вот здесь ошибка, что `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['userfile']['name']` не существует. А когда я такую работу сделаю (но только без данных, только загрузка) то работает...

Comment: Полностью код функции addNews выложите

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зачем вы велосипед создаете? У CodeIgniter есть встроенная библотека upload, ею и пользуйтесь для аплоада файлов. Читайте тут: [класс File Uploading](http://code-igniter.ru/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).

Comment: Ссылка мертва.Not Found. Желательно не приводить ссылки в качестве ответов.

Answer (score 0):

[Скрипт загрузки файлов](http://subcoder.ru/%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2/).